# Where are the gcov symbols?

Tags: gcc, profile, gcov

I'm trying to compile a simple app with gcov and getting the following link errors:

```
gcc AllTests.o CuTestTest.o CuTest.o -o TestTest
AllTests.o: In function `global constructors keyed to 0_RunAllTests':
/home/p7539c/cutest/AllTests.c:26: undefined reference to `__gcov_init'
AllTests.o:(.data+0x44): undefined reference to `__gcov_merge_add'
CuTestTest.o: In function `global constructors keyed to 0_TestCuStringNew':
/home/p7539c/cutest/CuTestTest.c:30: undefined reference to `__gcov_init'
CuTestTest.o:(.data+0x64): undefined reference to `__gcov_merge_add'
CuTest.o: In function `global constructors keyed to 0_CuStrAlloc':
/home/p7539c/cutest/CuTest.c:379: undefined reference to `__gcov_init'
CuTest.o:(.data+0x184): undefined reference to `__gcov_merge_add'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [TestTest] Error 1
```

I can't seem to find the location of the missing symbols. gcov is present on the machine running gcc version 4.1.2

Any ideas? Thanks.

On Edit:

Everything seems to work fine when using gcov with an application that consists of one .c file. When I have multiple .c files (hence multiple .o files) I have the above problem.

The compile steps look like the following:

```
cc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g   -c -o AllTests.o AllTests.c
cc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g   -c -o CuTestTest.o CuTestTest.c
cc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g   -c -o CuTest.o CuTest.c
```

Answer (score 84):

I just spent an incredible amount of time debugging a very similar error. Here's what I learned:

- You have to pass `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` when compiling.
- You have to pass `-fprofile-arcs` when linking.
- You can still get weird linker errors when linking. They'll look like this:

  `libname.a(objfile.o):(.ctors+0x0): undefined reference to 'global constructors keyed to long_name_of_file_and_function'`

This means that gconv's having problem with one of your compiler-generated constructors (in my case, a copy-constructor). Check the function mentioned in the error message, see what kinds of objects it copy-constructs, and see if any of those classes doesn't have a copy constructor. Add one, and the error will go away.

Edit: Whether or not you optimize can also affect this. Try turning on / switching off optimizations if you're having problems with it.

Comment: This works beautifully. Thanks for doing your incredible amount of time debugging.

Comment: Configuring the software with "CFLAGS="-O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage" LDFLAGS="-fprofile-arcs" ./configure <and so on>" seem to do the trick for me. Thanks.

Comment: @John146, @SlicedLime: It's a shame that this answer has not been accepted after two years. This just saved me a whole heap of time.

Comment: It seems it's not necessary to specify -fprofile-arcs in the LDFLAGS. Because these things done while creating the object files. The only thing you need is linking the libgcov in your program.

Answer (score 16):

The flag you're looking for is [-lgcov when linking](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-coverage-495).  That is, change:

```
gcc AllTests.o CuTestTest.o CuTest.o -o TestTest
```

to

```
gcc -lgcov AllTests.o CuTestTest.o CuTest.o -o TestTest
```

Comment: It is also possible to use `--coverage` instead of `-lgcov` as linker flag.

Answer (score 14):

I found, [as suggested here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/gcchelp/msg29518.html), that adding -lgcov to the build line when building a shared library that contains .o's built with -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage solved this for me.  And of course linking the executable with -lgcov.  Built the shared library like so:

```
g++    -shared -o libMyLib.so src_a.o src_b.o src_c.o -lgcov
```

And the executable like so:

```
g++ -o myExec myMain.o -lMyLib -lgcov
```

Adding the -lgov to the build of the shared library (not just the exe), solved this additional error for me:

```
hidden symbol `__gcov_merge_add' in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libgcov.a(_gcov_merge_add.o) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
```

Please note that -lgcov must be the last linked library.

Comment: Amazing. I tried to add new information when the developer uses CMake but the Suggested Edit was rejected... thanks, guys.

Comment: I'd prefer to write the next explanation within the answer. Anyway, with CMake, you can get the same behaviour adding `target_link_libraries (${LIBRARY_NAME} gcov)` after `target_link_libraries (${LIBRARY_NAME} gcov)`

Comment: This should be working. Not yet tried , I'll update my feedback after I tried.

Comment: The `Nonrepresentable section on output` error can happen if something compiled on your end declares something that's marked hidden but the dependency isn't satisfied internally.  For example: `extern __attribute__((visibility ("hidden"))) void some_function();`, where `some_function()` isn't provided at link time through an object or static library.

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to specify only `--coverage` on the command line when compiling and linking.

According to [`man gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-coverage-536):

> The option is a synonym for `-fprofile-arcs` `-ftest-coverage` (when
>   compiling) and `-lgcov` (when linking).

Answer (score 6):

I tried a simple test file with `gcc -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs test.c` and had no problems like you describe.

I suspect that gcc brings in the gcov library if the `-ftest-coverage` flag is there when it is linking. Try passing that flag on your gcc command line.

Comment: Tried that with a single file application and it works. I'm having problems with my multi-file application. It compiles fine, but seems to get confused linking.

Comment: p7539c@localhost cutest> make
    cc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g   -c -o AllTests.o AllTests.c
    cc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g   -c -o CuTestTest.o CuTestTest.c
    cc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g   -c -o CuTest.o CuTest.c
    gcc AllTests.o CuTestTest.o CuTest.o -o TestTest

Comment: You are still not passing the -ftest-coverage parameter in the final call to gcc. You need to specify it when linking too.

Comment: Like slicedlime says, it's not -ftest-coverage that is needed when linking but -fprofile-arcs.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps obviously, this exact error message is produced when linking with a non-gcc linker.  We seeing this error when linking with ifort (because our code includes both Fortran and C modules).  Switching to linking with gcc did the trick.

Comment: Since other linkers do not recognize the `-fprofile-arcs` option

Answer (score 2):

Great Max Lybbert,
Basically in case of autoconf usage add _LDADD = -lgcov ...

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

So I added -shared to the CFLAGS, and now it seems to work with multiple files. Of course, it's coring in a strange place, so I don't know what that's about yet.