# gcov final link failed

Tags: gcc, gcov

While compiling my project with gcov support I am facing the below error

Following are flags information i have while compiling

compiler flags:

```
CXXFLAGS="-Wno-deprecated -g -ggdb -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC"
```

linker options:

```
LINK_CMD="gcc -fprofile-arcs -fPIC"
```

Following are version information:

gcc version:

> gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)

gcov version:

> gcov (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)

error:

> hidden symbol `__gcov_init' in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libgcov.a(_gcov.o) is referenced by DSO
>   /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Could you please help me to get away from this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I have been able to solve this problem in my own code using these steps:

1. Make clean (remove all of my .o and lib files).
2. Ensure every source file has the correct options (-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage).
3. Ensure every shared library the source files are compiled into specify -lgcov
4. Ensure I link the executable with -lgcov.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4087557/13140) and [this blog post](http://tiptopsoftware.wordpress.com/2006/12/11/gcov-build-problem-hidden-sysmbol-__gcov_init-and-final-link-failed-nonrepresentable-section-on-output/).

Comment: Yep, I solved the problem linking my shared libraries with gcov.