# "Hidden symbol `atexit' is referenced by DSO" when using libtool with gcov

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, linker, libtool, gcov

I have a C++ project that uses the GNU Autotools for its build scripts and libtool for linking.  Recently I have added code coverage instrumentation with gcov, by ensuring that

```
GCOV_CFLAGS="-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
GCOV_LDFLAGS="-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
```

..get included in my `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` respectively.  On OS X 10.7.4 using g++-4.2 (installed by homebrew), everything works fine.

On Ubuntu 12.04 using g++ 4.6.3, libtool fails to link one of my tests:

```
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib   -o myproj/inttests/locale_test myproj/inttests/locale_test.o myproj/app/libapp.la -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt -pthread -llog4cplus  
libtool: link: g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -o myproj/inttests/.libs/locale_test myproj/inttests/locale_test.o -pthread  -L/usr/local/lib myproj/app/.libs/libapp.so -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt /usr/lib/liblog4cplus.so -pthread
/usr/bin/ld: myproj/inttests/.libs/locale_test: hidden symbol `atexit' in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(atexit.oS) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [myproj/inttests/locale_test] Error 1
```

How do I fix my build on ubuntu/g++ 4.6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After googling around I see [this thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/libtool/2011-05/msg00003.html), which suggests adding `--coverage` to `CXXFLAGS` when running `./configure`.  Indeed, though it didn't work for that poster, it works for me:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS="--coverage"
```

However this variable is reserved for the package installer, not the maintainer (me.) The question reduces to "How do I incorporate this into the build properly?"

Here's what's *not* enough:

```
GCOV_CFLAGS="-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage --coverage"
GCOV_LDFLAGS="-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
```

On the assumption that `GCOV_CFLAGS` gets included into the effective `CXXFLAGS` (not shown, but it does), it seems like this fix should work.  It doesn't.

Digging in further, it seems we should at least get some traction if we drop `CXXFLAGS="--coverage"` from the command line and instead place it in `configure.ac` somewhere.  This, actually, also did not work **unless** the line is placed above the `AC_PROG_CXX` call that selects the compiler.

So now we gain a little insight. `AC_PROG_CXX` is altering something when it sees `--coverage`, which is very likely why the placement in `GCOV_CFLAGS` didn't work: it was too late.

Looking carefully through the logs, it appears the secret sauce is the automatic inclusion of `-lgcov` in the failing linking step.  I'm not sure this library needed to be such a secret, but if I change my variables as so:

```
GCOV_CFLAGS="-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage --coverage"
GCOV_LDFLAGS="-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
GCOV_LIBS="-lgcov"
```

..and ensure `GCOV_LIBS` is included in `LIBS`, then it all works, on all my platforms.

**EDIT**: See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/566472/580412).

Comment: Do you manually work these GCOV* vars into other variables or are they automatically included? If you manually place them into others, which do you place them into?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the current version of my scripts do yet a third thing.  Take a peek at https://github.com/phs/sauce/blob/master/Makefile.am (see the `configure.ac` for `GCOV_ENABLED`)

Comment: This comment brought to you by the Department of Redundancy Department.

`--coverage` is the equivalent of `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` while compiling and `-lgcov` while linking.

Answer (score 1):

In a more generic way, this error can be fixed by making sure your libraries are ordered properly on your link command line.